# Centralize of hermitian normal linear functional

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ be two normal states on a von Neumann algebra $M$. We denote by $M_{\rho_1-\rho_2}$ the centralizer of $\rho_1-\rho_2$ and $M_{\rho_i}$ the centralizer of $\rho_i(i=1,2)$.

Does there exist relationship  between $M_{\rho_1-\rho_2}$ and $M_{\rho_1}$? Under What condition,can we conclude that $M_{\rho_1-\rho_2}\subset  M_{\rho_1}$?

Comment: What is the centralizer of a linear functional that is not positive?

Comment: We define $M_{\rho_1-\rho_2}=\{x\in M:x(\rho_1-\rho_2)=(\rho_1-\rho_2)x\}$, where $x(\rho_1-\rho_2)(y)=(\rho_1-\rho_2)(yx)$ and $(\rho_1-\rho_2)x y=(\rho_1-\rho_2)(xy)$ for any $y\in M$.